# colocar um load com jQuery no botão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera tenho um botão bem simples, porém queria saber se e possível colocar um loading no botão quando ele for clicado. Queria usar jquery.

Segue o código do meu botão.

```css
.button {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 42px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
  background-color: #FBBC05 !important;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="#">
  <button type='submit' class="button">GERAR</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quanto ao botão você poderia inserir uma imagem dentro ao clicar.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(this).html("<img src='http://cdn-frm-us.wargaming.net/4.5/style_images/wg/ajax_loading.gif' />");
});
```

```css
.button {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FBBC05 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" action="#">
  <button type='submit' class="button">GERAR</button>
</form>
```

Comment: caramba ficou muito bom. Bom percebi que vc usa a class '$(".button")', como faço para que o jquery carrega a função em todas as tag '< button>'?

Comment: Troque para o selector `$("button")` @HugoBorges.

Comment: ok, e possível tbm desabilitar o botão após ele ser clicado?

Comment: `$(this).prop("disabled",true);`